# How can I do a break now?

Tags: python, authentication, break

I began scripting today and don't know pretty much.
But how do I get it to end?

```
passwort = "Admin"
Logout = "Logout"
versuch = 0

while versuch != passwort:
    versuch = str(input("Passwort: "))

while versuch !=Logout:
    print ("Menu:Logout")
    vesuch = str(input(">"))

if str(input) == "Logout":
    print ("Do you really want to Logout?")
    print("Y / N")
```

Comment: type "Admin" , then enter, then "Logout" then enter

Comment: I don't think `str(input)` is going to do what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I get it to end". You begin scripting, you end scripting and do something else. Or if you were referring to "dont (sic) know pretty much", pick up a book about python programming, or hit some website with tutorials, start reading and you will end the state of not knowing much.

Comment: You also probably have a typo in the third assignment to `versuch` (you have `vesuch`)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is in second while loop:

```
while versuch !=Logout:
    print ("Menu:Logout")
    vesuch = str(input(">")) #Precisely here
```

You are not checking with the same variable in the while loop condition and in the assignment, may be mistyping mistake (in While loop condition it is: `versuch`, and in your assignment it is `vesuch`). so you should change it in your assignment to `versuch`

Another mistake here, is here:

```
if str(input) == "Logout":
```

you are not calling the `input` function here but just getting its reference, you need to add parenthesis to call the function: `input()`

Last thing, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` to avoid explicitly adding the double quotations in the user input otherwise it will not match, so with your code, if I enter : `Admin` , it will not match, but if I enter `"Admin"` it will work,
You don't want to bother the user to each time add the double quotations to their input, right?
Also don't need the str() function if you use `raw_input()` because it already returns a string

Comment: The OP's code is in Py3+ (print is function and not a statement!). There is no raw_input() here! input() returns a string whether you enter a number or a string!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Py3+ (which you are, judging by the print()) you don't have to explicitly convert the input to a string!

```
versuch = input("Passwort: ")
```

Doing the above is enough!

Coming to the if, you probably want to do something along the lines of:

```
while something:
    fooo foooo
    fooo foooo
    if versuch == "Logout":
        fooo
        if input() == "Y":
            break
```

Don't forget to indent it enough to put the if statement inside the while block!

PS: Welcome to Python!